# Downloading large photos from Photo Stream on iPad

Tags: ipad, photos, photo-stream

Downloading from Photo Stream gives me a small size picture (approx 200 KB) and I want to download the full size (1 to 2 MB) file. How can this be done?

What is the criteria for deleting my iPad photos? I have lost a lot of older photos without any notification or approval.

Comment: Hi Allan, welcome to Ask Different! You have two questions here and it will be preferable if you asked them separately

Answer (score 1):

On your first question, this is what the Apple My Photo Stream FAQ [says](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317):

> ### What resolution are My Photo Stream photos?
>
> On a Mac or PC, your photos are downloaded and stored in full
>   resolution. On iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple TV, your photos are
>   delivered in a device-optimized resolution that speeds downloads and
>   saves storage space. Dimensions will vary, but an optimized version of
>   a photo taken by a standard point-and-shoot camera will have a 2048 x
>   1536 pixel resolution when pushed to your devices. Panoramic photos
>   can be up to 5400 pixels wide.

On the second question, the Photo Stream criteria for deletion –not the images you took or saved with the device, which stay indefinitely on the Camera Roll– is defined as follows in the same document:

> ### How long are My Photo Stream photos stored in iCloud?
>
> The photos you upload to My Photo Stream are stored in iCloud for 30
>   days to give your devices plenty of time to connect and download them.
>
> ### How many photos are stored in My Photo Stream on my devices and computers?
>
> My Photo Stream pushes all your photos to the My Photo Stream album on
>   your devices and computers, and manages them efficiently, so you don’t
>   run out of storage space.
>
> Your iOS devices keep a rolling collection of your last 1000 photos in
>   the My Photo Stream album. From there, you can browse your recent
>   photos or move the ones you like to another album to keep them on your
>   device forever.